# Would you tell me more about using who/whom?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> To whom should I address the letter?
>
> To who should I address the letter?

Which one is correct or which one do you use?

Comment: [this might help you](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00042.htm) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dd1nQAjREAc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. To whom should I address the letter?
> 2. Whom should I address the letter to?
> 3. Who should I address the letter to?

All these example sentences are correct. And the following sentence is wrong.

> To who should I address the letter? *(Incorrect)*

"who" should be used in the subject position in a sentence, while "whom" should be used in the object position, and also after a preposition. For example:

> 1. Who made this decision? [here, who is the subject of the sentence]
> 2. Whom do you think we should support? [here, whom is the object of support]
> 3. To whom do you wish to speak? [here, whom is following the preposition to]

Comment: For #3, I'd probably say: _"Who should I address the letter to?"_ Whether that's "proper grammar" or not may be up for debate, but that's still how I'd probably phrase it in most conversations.

Comment: I also don't think adding a preposition at the end of the sentence is incorrect. But considering the wide range of debate over that matter I refrained myself from saying anything like that, or else I was actually planning to add that usage at the end of my answer.

Comment: I wasn't referring to the adding of a preposition at the end. I'm just not sure if that addition of a preposition means the correct word would be _whom_ instead of _who_. No matter – I'd still say "who", even if that wasn't strictly correct.

Comment: Who knows it exactly? I do not want any doubt.

Comment: :) What is your doubt? You should always trust a native speaker. And I am not one :) But I can try to clear your doubt. And here there is no contradiction in any of the above replies or comments.

Comment: I corrected my answer.